# How to change Android configuration of USB Host to autosuspend device without rooting

Tags: android, usb, root, suspend, usb-otg

I am working on an app that communicates to a device connected through the usb port.

The communication is made using a serial converter from FTDI, the FTD 230x. I am using the driver D2xx.

The problem i am having is that, when the device is connected to an ACER tablet (Model - Iconia One 7 B1-730), if it enters in sleep mode the device is supended saving battery power, but if the device is connected to a Samsung Tablet (Model-TM116), when it enters the sleep mode the device doesnt go to suspend mode and keeps draining battery.

Accessing the android shell i could verify that at "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/control" the Acer tablet is set to "auto", but on the Samsung it is set to "on". If i try to modify this value i get "permission denied".

Can i change this value without rooting the tablet, or is there a way to change the settings to turn on the autosuspend ?